# "Getting An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program" in doing build via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Hi  I am trying to trigger build for my Java application via JENKINS but getting following error:
An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/export/home/buildadmin/.jenkins/jobs/HEAD/workspace/appName/wasDeploy.sh" (in directory "/export/home/buildadmin/.jenkins/jobs/HEAD/workspace/appName"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory"
I have placed the wasDeploy.sh file in the above mentioned path but still getting the same error. Someone pleasee help me on this

Answer (score 0):

did you make wasDeploy.sh executable?

You can su to the jenkins user and try to run the file manually

Comment: Ya..I am running this file from EAR pom file and this is my code in pom.xml  <execution>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <configuration>
       <tasks name="Generate RMIC and Deployment code">
        <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${basedir}/wasDeploy.sh"
         failonerror="true">
         <arg line=""/>   
        </exec>
       </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>

Comment: not sure if this is your problem but you define ${basedir} as the directory and also in the executable. and is your job really called appName?

Comment: ${basedir} is my directory path from where it needs to pick wasDeploy.sh file. and dont want to reveal my CLient name thats why i have given job name as 'appName' over here.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered the same problem and thought I should share my solution.

Please check the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html), under the Description:

```
<property name="executable-full-path"
            location="../relative/path/to/executable"/>
<exec executable="${executable-full-path}" ...
```

And here is how I used this solution in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>expand-package</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <property name="executable-full-path" location="../test" />
                    <exec executable="${executable-full-path}/restart_service.sh" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to sh file of `Git` in `System Environment` variables.

The path usually is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.